# How to get real time log from cloud foundry?

Tags: logging, cloud-foundry

These days I am engaged to show real time log on a page when user deploy their apps.but meet some problem.

here is my solution:

1. Using Logstash to drain log from loggregator. my logstash config file is in the end of the question.
2. Invoke Elasticsearch RestAPI to read the most recent log(in 3 seconds) every 3 seconds and show it on a webpage.

**I am facing the following problems:**

1. the logs of [STG] kind never been drained. (I query it bothing using REST API and Kibana).
2. Other kind of logs sometimes not the same with the log I got from CLI(less than CLI,example is in the end of the question).

It seems that there is something wrong with my solution, because the CLI got the right logs, but after searching for days I still don't know where the problem is.

Any kind of advice will be helpful. Because I am a novice to CF.

ps. Please forgive my poor English...

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the command you used to create the user provided service (Check out http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/log-management-thirdparty-svc.html) for draining the logs?

When you setup the drain it logs messages from all points in Cloud Foundry related to your app.  The standard error/output, requests and responses from your app, as well as the requests through the cloud foundry router as well.

Could you possibly setup another user provided service, maybe Splunk, and see if the messages show up there?

Check out http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/streaming-logs.html#format for all the logging formats.